# Hbase recover deleted Rows

Tags: hadoop, hbase, backup

I use Hbase, I mistakenly deleted some rows (100 out of 100000000),
I would like to know if there is a way to restore and recover its supreme columns?
Know that I did not make any backup or snapshot!

Comment: seems not possible without low level fiddling. http://grokbase.com/t/hbase/user/129j6b54fj/undelete-rows. Backups?

Comment: When Delete command is issued through the HBase client, no data is actually deleted. Instead a tombstone marker is set, making the deleted cells effectively invisible.

User Scans and Gets automatically filter deleted cells until they get removed.
HBase periodically removes deleted cells during compactions. So check if your data still exists in hbase running scan command and write the logic to add it back. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/admin_writing_data_to_hbase.html